# Trying to make an image disappear after clicking it p5

Tags: arrays, image, p5.js

So I have very beginner knowledge with code, and am trying to make a 'forest' scene where the user can click on 5 little blobs of slime mould, and once they click on them they disappear.

Right now the 5 blobs of slime mould are there, but nothing is happening when they are clicked.

I copied a lot of this code from someone else but didn't get to see all their code so don't know what I'm missing.

I have no idea what to do from here, but this is my code:

Any help is appreciated :)

```
var slimeMould1x = 210;
var slimeMould1y = 550;
var slimeMould2x = 400;
var slimeMould2y = 540;
var slimeMould3x = 650;
var slimeMould3y = 560;
var slimeMould4x = 930;
var slimeMould4y = 580;
var slimeMould5x = 1100;
var slimeMould5y = 565;


var slimeMouldx = [210, 400, 650, 930, 1100];
var slimeMouldy = [550, 540, 560, 580, 565];
var slimeMouldClicked = [slimeMould1Clicked, slimeMould2Clicked, 
slimeMould3Clicked, slimeMould4Clicked, slimeMould5Clicked];
var slimeMould = [slimeMould1, slimeMould2, slimeMould3, slimeMould4, 
slimeMould5];

var forest;

function preload () {
slimeMould1 = loadImage("assets/slimemould-01.png");
slimeMould2 = loadImage("assets/slimemould-01.png");
slimeMould3 = loadImage("assets/slimemould-01.png");
slimeMould4 = loadImage("assets/slimemould-01.png");
slimeMould5 = loadImage("assets/slimemould-01.png");


forest = loadImage("assets/forest-03.png");
} 


function setup() {
  createCanvas(1200, 800);
     imageMode(CENTER);

}


function draw() {
  background(10);


  image(forest,width/2,height/2);


  fill(255);
  noStroke();
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(25);
  text("collect all the slime mould!", width/2, height*0.97);


     image(slimeMould1,slimeMould1x,slimeMould1y);
     image(slimeMould2,slimeMould2x,slimeMould2y);
     image(slimeMould3,slimeMould3x,slimeMould3y);
     image(slimeMould4,slimeMould4x,slimeMould4y);
     image(slimeMould5,slimeMould5x,slimeMould5y);


      slimeMould1Click();
      slimeMould2Click();
      slimeMould3Click();
      slimeMould4Click();
      slimeMould5Click();


   var noslimeMould = true;
    for (i = 0; i < slimeMould.length; i++){
        if (slimeMouldClicked[i] == false) {
           image(slimeMould[i], slimeMouldx[i], slimeMouldy[i]);
            noslimeMould = false;

        }
    }
}


function slimeMould1Click() {
    if (slimeMouldClicked[0] == false) {
        if ((mouseX > slimeMould1x) && (mouseX < (slimeMould1x+ 50)) && 
(mouseY > slimeMould1y) && (mouseY < (slimeMould1y+ 50))) {
            slimeMouldClicked[0] = true;
        }
    }
}


    function slimeMould2Click() {
       if (slimeMouldClicked[1] == false) {
        if ((mouseX > slimeMould2x) && (mouseX < (slimeMould2x+ 50)) && 
(mouseY > slimeMould2y) && (mouseY < (slimeMould2y+ 50))) {
            slimeMouldClicked[1] = true;
        }
     }
}


function slimeMould3Click() {
    if (slimeMouldClicked[2] == false) {
        if ((mouseX > slimeMould3x) && (mouseX < (slimeMould3x+ 50)) && 
(mouseY > slimeMould3y) && (mouseY < (slimeMould3y+ 50))) {
            slimeMouldClicked[2] = true;
        }
    }
}


    function slimeMould4Click() {
      if (slimeMouldClicked[3] == false) {
        if ((mouseX > slimeMould4x) && (mouseX < (slimeMould4x+ 50)) && 
(mouseY > slimeMould4y) && (mouseY < (slimeMould4y+ 50))) {
            slimeMouldClicked[3] = true;
        }
    }
}


    function slimeMould5Click() {
      if (slimeMouldClicked[4] == false) {
        if ((mouseX > slimeMould5x) && (mouseX < (slimeMould5x+ 50)) && 
(mouseY > slimeMould5y) && (mouseY < (slimeMould5y+ 50))) {
            slimeMouldClicked[4] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides the hard-coding, I think the main problem is that nowhere is the [mouseClicked()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseClicked) method or similar (mousePressed) are being called. Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TaN5At5RWH8) to get a better grasp of the issue.

Comment: I just added this:       

    function mousePressed() {
        slimeMould1Click();
        slimeMould2Click();
        slimeMould3Click();
        slimeMould4Click();
       slimeMould5Click();
        
    }

and still nothing is happening :(